# Point multiple CNAME records to a subdomain in cPanel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, cname

I want to point some subdomains to a single subdomain for a document library website I've created but I can't work out how to make the main subdomain show up by default. Eg.

library.site1.com
library.site2.com
library.site3.com

Point to library.mainsite.com

the default site is showing up on the mainsite hosting. It is currently shared hosting. Do I need to set a static ip for the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked this out.. By using addon domains on the mainsite. Once I added entries for each subdomain it started working. I did have to disable "allow users to park Subdomains" and "all domain parking across accounts" under tweak settings in whm.